# How to get state data while resolving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` for AngularJS.

I've defined some states like this.

```
    $stateProvider.state(
        {
            name:       'home',
            url:        '^/?page&find',
            controller: controller,
            data:       new cgTag.States.StateData('home', type),
            resolve:    resolve
        }
    );
```

I'm using a resolve to get some JSON from the server before the controller for the state is executed, but I need the `state.data` object for this state in the resolve function.

My resolver is like this

```
function _resolve($http, $state, $stateParams)
{
    var data = $state.current.data;
    // ^^^^ this is the wrong state
    return $http.post('/json/templates/layout', data);
}

var resolve = {
    'layoutResponse': ['$http', '$state', '$stateParams', _resolve]
};

$stateProvider.state(
    {
        name:       'home',
        url:        '^/?page&find',
        controller: controller,
        data:       new cgTag.States.StateData('home', type),
        // ^^^ I need this object in my resolve function.
        resolve:    resolve
    }
);
```

My problem is that `$state.current` is not the state being transitioned too. It's the from state.

How can I get the `state.data` object inside my resolve function for the state being resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the data for the current state by calling `this.data` from within the resolve function.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('someState', {
    url: '/',
    resolve: {
      resolveThis: function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.data)); // alerts you with delicious bacon
      }
    },
    data: {
      bacon: 'delicious'
    }
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OMc5ilofyA4sv66JMQe9?p=info